# I need to change the color of the rectangles with the fitz library in python

Tags: python, pdf, pymupdf

I have made this code in Python with the Fitz library, what I want is to change the color of the rectangles and to do so it accesses the fill part but it does not change it, if someone can help me

I was trying with this code, but you don't change it for me

```
import fitz

Ruta del archivo PDF
pdf_path = "rectangulos.pdf"

Abrir el archivo PDF
pdf_document = fitz.open(pdf_path)

Recorrer cada página del PDF
for page_number in range(len(pdf_document)):
Obtener la página actual
page = pdf_document[page_number]
page_drawings = page.get_drawings()

for drawing in page_drawings:

if drawing['items'][0][0] == 're':

drawing['fill'] = (1, 1, 1)

Guardar los cambios en un nuevo archivo PDF    
output_pdf_path = "rectangulos_modificados.pdf"
pdf_document.save(output_pdf_path)

print("¡Se ha modificado el color de todos los rectángulos a rojo en el archivo PDF!")]</kbd>`
```

Comment: Your indentation is busted, try to paste the code with proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem involves what is being returned by `page.get_drawings()`, which is just a list of dictionaries (see [the fitz docs](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/page.html#Page.get_drawings)). Essentially, modifying a dictionary only effects the dictionary (there are no side effects from this modification in the page or fitz objects). To create a modified version you will need to modify a fitz Page object (either from the existing pdf_document or a new fitz object). A simple example of adding a shape to a page is

```
for page in pdf_document:
   shape = page.new_shape()

   shape.drawRect(fitz.Rect(x0, y0, x1, y1))
   shape.finish(fill=(1, 1, 1))
   shape.commit()  # Apply the changes to the page
```

Notice the very purposeful `commit` to apply changes to shape, which is 'owned' by the Page object. You'd want to use the existing shapes to inform the geometry of the new shapes. Hopefully this sets you in the right direction! Keep making things =)

I'm also assuming the correctly formatted code is the following

```
import fitz

# Ruta del archivo PDF
pdf_path = "rectangulos.pdf"

# Abrir el archivo PDF
pdf_document = fitz.open(pdf_path)

# Recorrer cada página del PDF
for page_number in range(len(pdf_document)):
    # Obtener la página actual
    page = pdf_document[page_number]
    page_drawings = page.get_drawings()

    for drawing in page_drawings:
        if drawing['items'][0][0] == 're':
            drawing['fill'] = (1, 1, 1)

# Guardar los cambios en un nuevo archivo PDF
output_pdf_path = "rectangulos_modificados.pdf"
pdf_document.save(output_pdf_path)
```